# Is is possible to sync my Samsung Galaxy S with an exchange account, but only the calendar, not the emails?

Tags: sync, calendar, exchange

I managed to **sync** my Galaxy Samsung S running Froyo with **an exchange server**.

But I am really **only interested in the calender data, not the emails**.

Someone knows how to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope someone comes up with a different solution: as far as I can tell, the solution presented in the answer by Al Everett, doesn't work.

*My work around* : I have **created a folder called 'Inbox server'** on the exchange and set up a **filter to move all incoming mails from inbox to 'inbox server'**.

Since the sync only syncs the inbox folder by default , effectively, **no exchange emails are synced now**.

But if anyone else has another solution or comments, please let them know. I will be glad to read them.

Answer (score 2):

Try this: Go to the account for the Exchange server and change "Email check frequency" to "Never". Check the box to "Sync calendar".

Comment: @Al Everett: I might be mistaking but I think that no calendar information is sync'd when this option is cleared. I will try again, but I think I already tried this a couple of days ago.

Comment: If it doesn't work, then as far as I can see there is no way to sync to Exchange WITHOUT getting the e-mail.

Comment: I use this configuration every day. It works. (Epic 4G)

Comment: @TREE: AFAIK when you set the email check frequency to never, it means that this account will not be checked regularly. If you set sync on, it still sync the calendar AND the mail. At least I haven't found a way to not sync the emails.

Comment: This could be a difference in specific versions of the Samsung software. If I set email check frequency to "Never" my calendar definitely still syncs. It isn't instant like push, but IIRC the calendar is never instant. Basically, you can't control the calendar sync frequency whatsoever.