# Exchange email syncs even if I disable it (only want to sync calendar)

Tags: email, calendar, exchange, active-sync

I only want to sync Exchange calendar, not email.

In the Exchange Account's options, I never checked "sync email", and it still synced after a few hours. I retried from scratch, and same thing happened again.
Anyone experience this, do you have a workaround?

Also I tried uninstalling the stock Email app, but unfortunately then you can't even add Exchange accounts. :(

Android version 4.4.2

Comment: Seems to be addressed here already: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4607/is-is-possible-to-sync-my-samsung-galaxy-s-with-an-exchange-account-but-only-th